# How to remove default color theme of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I'm editing a custom application with Visual Studio Shell 2015 as base. It comes with 3 defaults themes:

- Blue
- Dark
- Light

[image: Color theme options]

Is there a way to remove the Dark theme?

I searched Stack Overflow and the most relevant question is this one: [How to get current used color theme of Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920572/how-to-get-current-used-color-theme-of-visual-studio)

Comment: Don't know about Shell apps, but for VS itself you can remove the Dark theme by deleting the key `{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}` under `HKCR\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\Themes`, or just renaming it to an "illegal" name such as `// {1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}`. Of course, you should check it's not the currently active theme prior to removing it.

Comment: Thank you dxiv. I tried it and it indeed remove the Dark option in Visual Studio. However when I do the same for Shell app, it regrows the registry key whenever I restart the computer

Comment: [Elements of the Isolated Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/visualstudio/extensibility/elements-of-the-isolated-shell?view=vs-2015) points to registry settings being restored from `.pkgdef` files, but I haven't played with shell apps so can't give advice there.

Comment: Glad it helped, and +1 for taking the time to post an answer proper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of dxiv, I found out how to remove default theme:

Find the file *.pkgundef in your application.
Add this line:

```
[$RootKey$\Themes\{1ded0138-47ce-435e-84ef-9ec1f439b749}]
```